# Virtualmin Centos8 Apache .htaccess not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualmin

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 https://sub.mydomain.org/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 https://sub.mydomain.org/500.html

RewriteRule ^(test)$ test.php [NC,L,END]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ route.php?params=$1
```

I've these simple lines in my .htaccess file.
My website was working with this .htaccess file on cPanel hosted cloud, then i've moved my website virtualmin and htaccess rules not working properly.

I mean if i type urle https://sub.mydomain.org/hello it redirects route.php?params=hello and route.php simple write hello.

but if i type browser https://sub.mydomain.org/test it is going to infinity loop then go to 404 page.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have any other rules in your .htaccess file? Or these are the only rules you have.

Comment: Also your 1st rule has `END` section in it, so IMHO I don't think so your 2nd rule is coming in picture if 1st is matched.

Comment: I've tested with these rules, but it didn't work, also when i try simple remove .php extension rules for .htacess didn't work. (it works with cpanel) the problem is even the rule matched, END section rule didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

i've solved my problem by adding this line into htaccess file after  **RewriteBase /** rule.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

error was:

[Thu Dec 31 08:31:21.144052 2020] [negotiation:error] [pid 374984:tid 140529417303808] [client 78.163.24.43:53811] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/user/public_html/test (None could be negotiated)., referer: https://sub.mydomain.org/

Comment: You saved my day